# maven site plugin unable to load mojo

Tags: deployment, maven-2, ear, build-error

I´m trying to deploy my maven ear project but I´m getting this **error** while doing, mvn install in the pom proyect(my IDE is eclipse)

```
C:\temp\eat>mvn clean install -e
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order:
[INFO]   eat application
[INFO]   eat utility module
[INFO]   eat EJB module
[INFO]   eat Web module
[INFO]   eat EAR module
[INFO]   eat integration tests module
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building eat application
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
-----------------------------------------------------
this realm = app0.child-container[org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0
-beta-7]
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/luis.cabezas/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/ma
ven-site-plugin/2.0-beta-7/maven-site-plugin-2.0-beta-7.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/luis.cabezas/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-
utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Number of imports: 10
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@a6c57a42
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@12f43f3b
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@20025374
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@f8e44ca4
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@92758522
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@ebf2705b
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@bb25e54
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@bece5185
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@3fee8e37
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@3fee19d8

this realm = plexus.core
urls[0] = file:/C:/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/../lib/maven-2.2.1-uber.jar
Number of imports: 10
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@a6c57a42
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@12f43f3b
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@20025374
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@f8e44ca4
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@92758522
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@ebf2705b
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@bb25e54
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@bece5185
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@3fee8e37
import: org.codehaus.classworlds.Entry@3fee19d8
----------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.apache.maven.plu
gins:maven-site-plugin:2.0-beta-7:attach-descriptor': Unable to load the mojo 'o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0-beta-7:attach-descriptor' in the p
lugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin'. A required class is missing:
org/apache/maven/doxia/tools/SiteToolException
org.apache.maven.doxia.tools.SiteToolException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Internal error in the pl
ugin manager executing goal 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0-beta
-7:attach-descriptor': Unable to load the mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-s
ite-plugin:2.0-beta-7:attach-descriptor' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins
:maven-site-plugin'. A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/doxia/tools/S
iteToolException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(Defa
ultLifecycleExecutor.java:698)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLi
fecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(Defau
ltLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHan
dleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegmen
ts(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLi
fecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl. java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManagerException: Unable to load the mo
jo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0-beta-7:attach-descriptor' in
the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin'. A required class is mis
sing: org/apache/maven/doxia/tools/SiteToolException
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(Defaul
tPluginManager.java:669)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPlugi
nManager.java:468)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(Defa
ultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
  ... 17 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupExc
eption: Unable to lookup component 'org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojoorg.apache.maven
.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0-beta-7:attach-descriptor', it could not be created at      org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContai
ner.java:335)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:440)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(Defaul
tPluginManager.java:652)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.factory.ComponentInstantiationException
: Could not instanciate component: role: 'null', implementation: 'org.apache.mav
en.plugins.site.SiteDescriptorAttachMojo'
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.factory.java.JavaComponentFactory.makeE
xception(JavaComponentFactory.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.factory.java.JavaComponentFactory.newIn
stance(JavaComponentFactory.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.createComponentInstance(De
faultPlexusContainer.java:1464)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.create
ComponentInstance(AbstractComponentManager.java:93)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.PerLookupComponentManager.getCo
mponent(PerLookupComponentManager.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContai
ner.java:331)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/doxia/tools/SiteTool
Exception
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.factory.java.JavaComponentFactory.newIn
stance(JavaComponentFactory.java:44)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.doxia.tools.SiteTo
olException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassL
oader.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassReal
m.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassReal
m.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.
java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 31 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Mar 04 16:01:47 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
```

**this is my parent.pom**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.eat</groupId>
<artifactId>eat</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>eat application</name>
<build>
 <pluginManagement>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.2.SP1</version>
   <configuration>
<source>${java.version}</source>
<target>${java.version}</target>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.4.1</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.4.3</version>
 <configuration>
<excludedGroups>${tests.excludedGroups}</excludedGroups>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
<modules>
<module>eat-util</module>
<module>eat-ejb</module>
<module>eat-web</module>
<module>eat-ear</module>
<module>eat-tests</module>
</modules>
```

**ear.pom**

```
 <parent>
 <artifactId>eat</artifactId>
 <groupId>com.eat</groupId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
 <groupId>com.eat</groupId>
 <artifactId>eat-ear</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>ear</packaging>
 <name>eat EAR module</name>
<build>
  <finalName>eat-ear</finalName>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
            <version>5</version>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <earSourceExcludes>**/application.xml, **/jboss-app.xml</earSourceExcludes>
        <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
        <jboss>
          <version>4.2.3</version>
           <loader-repository>seam.jboss.org:loader=eat-ear.ear</loader-repository>
        </jboss>
        <modules>
         <webModule>
          <groupId>com.eat</groupId>
          <artifactId>eat-web</artifactId>
          <contextRoot>/eat</contextRoot>
          <bundleFileName>eat-web.war</bundleFileName>
        </webModule>
        <ejbModule>
         <groupId>com.eat</groupId>
         <artifactId>eat-ejb</artifactId>
         <bundleFileName>eat-ejb.jar</bundleFileName>
        </ejbModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

**war.pom**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>eat</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.eat</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.eat</groupId>
  <artifactId>eat-web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>eat Web module</name>
```

**ejb.pom**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>eat</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.eat</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.eat</groupId>
  <artifactId>eat-ejb</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>ejb</packaging>
  <name>eat EJB module</name>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
    <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

I don´t know if this is enough information. if is not, tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Aditional info:
Maven version: 2.2.1
JDK version: 1.6.0.29

Comment: The exception is quite clear as `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0-beta-7:attach-descriptor`. I understand that there is somewhere in you `pom.xml` defines the `maven-site-plugin`. The further suspected is that the artifact required by `maven-site-plugin` is missing as well. Could you please provide the pom.xml which may be contains the `maven-site-plugin`?